# Cannot get node-inspector working

Tags: node.js, express, node-inspector

I have a basic express app that I am trying to debug but I cannot get node inspector working correctly on OSX

In one terminal window I run:

```
node --debug-brk server.js
```

In another terminal window I run:

```
node-inspector
```

Node Inspector opens here:

```
http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858
```

In another browser tab I try to open my site here

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

I get printed to screen

```
Cannot GET /
```

If I open instead

```
http://localhost:3000
```

I get my app because I set this in server.js

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

But now none of the breakpoints work in the debugger

I am sure I am doing something stupid here but I have read the docs and tutorials over and over and I cannot get this to work.

The other things I have tried is in one terminal window running:

```
node-debug server.js
```

I get the same thing as above. Debug inspector opens and is stopped at first line and my site at

```
http://localhost:8080
```

still says

```
Cannot GET /
```

I also tried

```
node-debug --no-debug-brk server.js
```

An I get the same result except node inspector in not stopped at first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Debug inspector opens and is stopped at first line...

When `node-inspector` starts debugging an application, by default, it stops at the first line, during the app starting process. If you try to access your app at `http://localhost:3000` with the debugger stopped at the first line, you'll never get to your breakpoints.

Before trying anything, you must resume script execution or start `node-inspector` with the `--no-debug-brk` option, to prevent stopping at the first line.

To make sure `node-inspector` is not stopping at any line at all, what you should do:

- put a breakpoint at the line where you have your `app.listen` call, or;
- a more *extreme* solution: put a breakpoint at every line of your main file.

Comment: Ok this kind of works. I have a routes file (that is referenced from main server.js file) that contains:

router.get('/api/projects', projects.getProjects);

If I put breakpoint on that line nothing happens even though this route is being hit. Similarly if I add a breakpoint anywhere in my main server.js file nothing happens. But if I add a breakpoint in getProjects function in projects controller (projects.getProjects) it hits the breakpoint now and pauses the debugger correctly. The next question is why are the breakpoints in the two previous files not being hit (server.js -> routes.js?)

Comment: On further thought could it be that once the main server.js file is loaded it is never executing that code again after the server starts up??

Comment: It all depends on how your app is written, but IMO, it's now another problem. What I suggest: ask another question explaining that problem about the app flow and post the code of those three files that you've mentioned. I'll be glad to try to figure out the problem with you. The actual problem (about node-inspector) is solved now.